# how to get all data from array in a variable?

Tags: php

I have a dynamic array like

```
Array
(
[company_name] => a
[address] => b
[country_id] => 1
[email] => c@c.com
[currency_id] => 1
)
```

and i want to create a index variable like:

```
`$var = "company_name,address,country_id,email,currency_id";`
```

and value variable like:

```
$value = "a,b,1,c@c.com,1";
```

remember that array index and value not fixed.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this.

```
$var = implode(',', array_keys($myArray));

$value = implode(',', array_values($myArray));
```

Where `$myArray` is the array you showed in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) and [`array_values()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) functions.

---

Consider you have an array like this:

```
$arr = array(
    'company_name' => 'a',
    'address' => 'b',
    'country_id' => 1,
    'email' => 'c@c.com',
    'currency_id' => 1
);
```

Use `array_keys()` function to get all keys:

```
$keys = array_keys($arr);
print_r($keys);

// output
// Array
// (
//     [0] => company_name
//     [1] => address
//     [2] => country_id
//     [3] => email
//     [4] => currency_id
// )
```

Then you can use `implode` to convert array to string:

```
$k = implode($keys, ',');
echo $k;
// company_name,address,country_id,email,currency_id
```

And for values such that, instead we use `array_values()` function:

```
$vals = array_values($arr);
print_r($vals);

// output
// Array
// (
//     [0] => a
//     [1] => b
//     [2] => 1
//     [3] => c@c.com
//     [4] => 1
// )
```

And then implode it:

```
$v = implode($vals, ',');
echo $v;
// a,b,1,c@c.com,1
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you mean?

```
$keys=implode(',',array_keys($a));
$vals=implode(',',array_values($a));
```